# c++ passing a pointer to a function that takes a reference

Tags: c++

I have the following functions in two classes:

```
Student::Student(const string & FName, const string & LName, const int ID){
    first = FName;
    last = LName;
    id = ID;
```

the above function in the `student` class, and the code below in the `students` class

```
Students::Students(){

}
    void Students::add(Student & aStudent){     
            collection.push_back(&aStudent);
}
```

where `collection` is a vector that is a private member of the `Students` class. In my main function, I create a student with the following:

```
student* bob = new student ("Bob" "Jones" 10000909);
```

I want to now add this student to the vector of students. I have tried various code such as below:

```
students::add(bob)
students::add(*bob)
```

However, these both result in errors such as:

```
no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘Student*’ to ‘Student&’
```

I was wondering what I am doing wrong when trying to add students.

Main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "student.h"
#include "students.h"
using namespace std;


int main(){
  Student* bob = new Student ("Bob" "Jones" 10000909);
  Students::add(bob); //error occurs  
  return 0;

}
```

Student h:

```
#include <ostream>
#include <string>  
class Student {

    public:
    StudentStudent(const string & FName, const string & LName, const int ID);

    private:

    string first;
    string last;
    int id;

};
```

students h:

```
#include <ostream>
#include <vector>
#include "student.h"
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Students {

    public:
    Students(); 
    void add(Student & aStudent);

    private:

    vector<Student*> collection;

};
```

Comment: 1. Use initialisation lists in the contructor. 2. Avoid using plurals as a class names - very easy to confuse `Student` and `Students` - this will avoid errors/make debugging easier

Comment: Why are you using `new` to create a `Student`?  This: `students::add(*bob)` results in a memory leak, unless you saved the pointer `bob` somewhere for later deletion.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Please add an example that we can run, so we can help you better.

Comment: How is `collection` defined? Please post a [mcve].

Comment: What's `student` and `students` (lowercase `s`)? How, if  at all, are they related to `Student` and `Students`?

Comment: How is declared `students` ? Is it an instance of `Students` ?

Comment: Added .h files for clarification

Comment: `add` is not a static member of `Students`, therefore `Students::add(...)` is not a valid syntax. You need an instance of `Students` on which to call `add`.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik could you give an example of what you mean?

Comment: `Students group; group.add(*bob);`

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I am looking to add these students into a vector, and then have the user be able to delete students out of the vector when they want based on student Id. I assume I can create some sort of destructor to ensure no memory leaks?

Comment: @MastRofDsastR -- You don't need any dynamic memory allocation to remove an item from a vector or `new` to create `Student` instances.  C++ is not Java.

Comment: @MastRofDsastR -- [As seen here](https://www.ideone.com/kpUsko).  No calls to `new` or `delete`.

Answer (score 0):

I would rewrite your main:

```
int main(void)
{
      Student bob("Bob", "Jones",  10000909);
      Students aStudents;
      aStudents.add(bob);
}
```

But I would also store reference in the vector and not pointers.